# Set 'WE8ISO8859P15' character set for existing Oracle 19c DB while migrating 12c DB

Tags: oracle-12c, migration, character-set, oracle-19c

I have a database in 12c (12.2.0.1) which I need to migrate to an existing live oracle 19c DB.(This DB already hosts a couple of live DBs’s)

Character set  of DB’s are as below:

- 12c ->  WE8ISO8859P15
- 19c ->  AL32UTF8

#### First approach I tried as follows

I created a PDB PDBTST20 in Oracle 19c and then with the below commands performed the PDB character set conversion from `AL322UTF8` to `WE8ISO8859P15` successfully. After the change of character set I also performed an export from 12c and import into 19c. This also got executed successfully without any errors.

```
SQL> alter pluggable database PDBTST20 close immediate;
SQL> alter pluggable database PDBTST20 open restricted;
SQL> ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER  SET INTERNAL_USE WE8ISO8859P15 ;

Database altered.
```

However I came across an article [Can you select a PDB’s character set?](https://mikedietrichde.com/2017/10/23/can-you-select-a-pdbs-character-set/) (Mike Deitrich)  which warns against using this command.

#### Questions

Can you experts please confirm/comment on the approach I have taken is right? If not, can you please suggest me the correct approach for the same?

Its little urgent.

#### Alternate Approaches

I tried a few other approaches for PDB creation, but faced issues listed below:

1. Move PDB from one container to another. that is relocate it from CDB1 to CDB2. However, this also threw invalid errors for `sys` related objects.
2. Database Migration Assistant for Unicode (DMU). However facing issues with operating the tool as it is very slow to the point of hanging.
   a. Use this tool to Validate the migration.
   b. Use this tool to perform the migration.
   c. A check to import of data with `set internal use`  parameter to verify whether data import is successful.
   d. Perform  import on container 2 (CDB with the desired character set)

But none of the a),b),c) and d) approaches are working. I am stuck.

Any immediate confirmed help/pointers will be a help to me.

Comment: Did you check MOS(My Oracle Support)? (You'll need an Oracle Support subscription)

Comment: Agree that MOS will be needed; but just curious, your original approach yielded no errors, right?  Did you check some of the data that could be suspect?  What operating system?